# Get the inner content of a gzipped SVG file with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js, svg

I am trying to get the content of a gzipped SVG file using ajax call and then control the inner elements of it using jquery and d3.js . Right now, I am printing all the inner content of the SVG file into the HTML which leads to a large amount of sever load. I couldn't find a solution. What is the best way to achieve it?!

Comment: If the SVG file is being served with the correct header (`Content-Encoding: gzip`), then by the time the front end sees it, it should be uncompressed.  Then it just becomes a matter of inserting the XML into the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://somewhere.net/file.svg",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```